# Pip and resolving repository requirements

Tags: python, pip

Is pip supposed to resolve requirements that have requirements that are not on pypi but in a different repository?

Consider there are three packages, `package1`, `package2` and `package3`.

The requirements.txt of `package1` looks like:

```
Django==1.4.1
-e svn+http://example.com/package2/svn/trunk#egg=package2
```

And the requirements.txt of `package2` like:

```
django-mptt==0.5.2
-e svn+http://example.com/package3/svn/trunk#egg=package3
```

Installing the requirements with `pip install -r requirements.txt` of `package1` installs:

- Django
- package2
- django-mptt

So the requirement of `package2` available through pypi (django-mptt) is resolved, but the repository requirement `package3` is not.

Is this simply something pip can't handle on its own? Can it be done at all (through the setup.py of `package2` for example), or do these kind of requirements have to be installed manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pip doesn't watch requirements.txt in installed packages, but in setup.py, you should add package3 to package2 `install_requires` and add `dependency_links` like:

```
dependency_links=[
      "svn://example.com/package3/svn/trunk#egg=package3"
  ]
```